# SQL SERVER: Define same database collation for temporary table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, collation, temp-tables

I have a script in SQL Server. In that script I create a temporary table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE #tmpTbl(ID char(36) NOT NULL, Field1 char(36) NOT NULL, Field2 varchar(50) NOT NULL, Field3 varchar(50))
```

to set the collation for entire temporary table I do:

```
CREATE TABLE #tmpTbl(ID char(36) collate Modern_Spanish_CI_AS NOT NULL , Field1 char(36) collate Modern_Spanish_CI_AS NOT NULL , Field2 varchar(50) collate Modern_Spanish_CI_AS NOT NULL , Field3 varchar(50) collate Modern_Spanish_CI_AS)
```

As you see, I apply collation for each column. So I am trying to do below:

1. Instead of applying collation to each column of the temporary table, is there any possibility to apply collation to all columns of temporary table at onces?
2. Instead of indicating manually the collation Modern_Spanish_CI_AS that the database where script is executed has, is there any way to get the collation from the database through a variable and then set it to temporary columns?

for example in this last case:

```
DECLARE @Collation = getdatabasecollation  --> Get current database collation where script is executed.
```

and then:

```
CREATE TABLE #tmpTbl(ID char(36) collate @Collation NOT NULL , Field1 char(36) collate @Collation NOT NULL, Field2 varchar(50) collate @Collation NOT NULL , Field3 varchar(50) collate @Collation)
```

or has I have told in point 1, set this collation to entire temporary table.

Comment: If you don't use ASCII types, you don't need to set collations

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: collation is relevant for all character columns, regardless of the characters they actually contain. Expressions that combine columns with different collations will result in errors. You cannot choose to "not set collations"; if you don't, the database default will be used. This will only work as long as all databases use the same collation, which is common but by no means universal.

Comment: @JeroenMostert relevant yes, a problem, not so much. With ASCII, you can't even join or search if the collation is wrong. That's a critical problem. With nvarchar, in rare cases you *may* miss an index when joining tables from multiple databases. The query will still work. And I do work on non-US systems.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "ASCII". If you mean `CHAR`/`VARCHAR`, then yes, the characters they support are restricted by collation, whereas `NCHAR`/`NVARCHAR` are not. Collation will still influence comparisons regardless of character type used, though, and will still result in errors when you mix different collations (even if those collations are compatible in terms of the characters they support).

Comment: In the case of the OP specifically, if SQL Server was installed with a default collation that is not `Modern_Spanish_CI_AS`, then a user database is created that uses `Modern_Spanish_CI_AS`, `tempdb` will have an incompatible collation, and you need to solve exactly the problem asked here when joining tables. This is true even if you were to use `NCHAR`/`NVARCHAR` throughout.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT`

```
CREATE TABLE #tmpTbl
  (
     ID     CHAR(36) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT NOT NULL,
     Field1 CHAR(36) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT NOT NULL,
     Field2 VARCHAR(50) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT NOT NULL,
     Field3 VARCHAR(50) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT NULL
  )
```

Comment: But if my database has collation Modern_Spanish_CI_AS, will DATABASE_DEFAULT return Modern_Spanish_CI_AS? And if in a future I change database collation to another say  Latin1_General_CI_AS, will then DATABASE_DEFAULT return  Latin1_General_CI_AS?

Comment: @user1624552 yes [You can also use the database_default option in the COLLATE clause to specify that a column in a temporary table use the collation default of the current user database for the connection instead of tempdb.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/collations)

Comment: of course if you create the temp table and then change the default database collation the already existing temp table won't change collation though. It applies at table create time.

Comment: A lot of thanks Martin, I set COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT to all my temporary table columns in creation time and it works like a charm!